# How reset number of PiD

Tags: python, linux, nanopi

One thread in my python program check CPU use, in big simplification it look like this:

```
import time
import commands
while 1:
    example=commands.getstatusoutput('iostat')
    time.sleep(1)
```

after few days of work, program stop working, because:
"socket: too many open files"
I use all PiD number

I know that i can change number in cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max, but i would like "reset" numer of PiD. It is possibile without reset of whole device?

Comment: `iostat` with no arguments runs continuously. Would you rather run `iostat 1 1`, which will run for a few seconds and then exit?

Comment: That's as undesirable as spawning a `top` per second ... what are you trying to achieve, stress the machine?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import signal

os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM) #or signal.SIGKILL
```

you have to kill the processes...